# VBA IF Then Vlookup Multiple Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve data from another file using the VLOOKUP function however this is only to happen depending on if any of the 2 items of data appear in column 3(C)

"PO Materials"  OR
"PO Labor"

```
Sub MakeFormulas()

Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim OutputLastRow As Long
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
Dim X As Long

'What are the names of our worksheets?
Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")


'Determine last row of source
With sourceSheet
    SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With outputSheet

    'Determine last row in col C
    OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For X = 5 To OutputLastRow
        If InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Materials") > 0 Then
            'Apply our formula
        .Range("Q2:Q" & OutputLastRow).Formula = _
            "=VLOOKUP(E2,'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$B$" & SourceLastRow & ",2,0)"
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Code is working; However, its giving #N/A if the cell is blank or contains any value in Column C, which means its not recognizing the If statement.  If the column does not containn "PO Materials" or "PO Labor" I would like it to skip to the next cell in the range

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Your `If` statement is rendered null since you're applying your formula to an entire range (`"Q2:Q" & OutputLastRow`) every time the loop is run. So, if your condition is true at least once, the entire range will have the formula in it regardless.

Comment: Ok now it partially works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that generates the VLOOKUP is applying that formula to each cell in the column every time.  That is, every time your `If` condition finds "PO Materials", it will apply the VLOOUKP to every cell between Q2 and the last row from column E.

I think this is what you want:

```
.Range("Q" & X).Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP(E" & X & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$B$" & SourceLastRow & ",2,0)"
```

Alternatively, it could be done completely within the spreadsheet:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("PO Materials",C6)),"",VLOOKUP(E6,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Final Code for future reference

```
Sub MakeFormulas()
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim OutputLastRow As Long
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
Dim X As Long

'What are the names of our worksheets?
Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")


'Determine last row of source
With sourceSheet
SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
With outputSheet

'Determine last row in col C
OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For X = 2 To OutputLastRow
If InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Materials") + InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Labor") > 0 Then
    'Apply our formula
.Range("Q" & X).Formula = _
"=VLOOKUP(E" & X & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$B$" & SourceLastRow & ",2,0)"
End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```